# How to return only specific columns in a query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables in my db, first one is Customers, and second Sessions. I need to make a query that selects all the customers’ details for sessions booked on a Monday. First query runs with no errors, but its returning the information from both customers and sessions, i need something that presents only customers, similar to second code(which does not work.)

```
//First working code
SELECT *
FROM Customers
LEFT OUTER JOIN Sessions
ON Customers.CustomerRefNo=Sessions.CustomerRefNo WHERE 
WEEKDAY(Sessions.DateOfSession) = 0;


//Second not working code
SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE Customers.CustomerRefNo=Sessions.CustomerRefNo AND 
WEEKDAY(Sessions.DateOfSession) = 0;
```

Comment: SELECT Customers.*

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the columns that you want instead of `*` which returns all the columns. If you really want to use the `*`, you can qualify it with the name of the table and it will return all columns from that table, like this:

```
SELECT Customers.*
FROM Customers
LEFT OUTER JOIN Sessions
ON Customers.CustomerRefNo=Sessions.CustomerRefNo WHERE 
WEEKDAY(Sessions.DateOfSession) = 0;
```

Comment: IT WORKS! Thanks for your time :)